# What is the role of https.Agent in Node?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, tls1.2

In the Node [https module docs](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_url_options_callback),
regarding `https.request`, an example is shown:

```js
const options = {
  hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};
options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  // ...
});
```

This example is slightly ambiguous in my opinion, and I've asked an [SO question regarding this ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64076241/why-does-node-https-module-documentation-example-pass-tls-options-to-both-the-ag) and following a comment reaffirming the strange wording, [opened an issue for this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/35360).

Regardless, I am still trying to understand the part that the Agent plays in this scenario, seeing as the `https.Agent` module does accept TLS connection options:

```ts
interface AgentOptions extends http.AgentOptions, tls.ConnectionOptions
```

The definition of the [https.Agent](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_class_https_agent) object is:

> An Agent object for HTTPS similar to http.Agent.

And the definition for the [http.Agent](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) object is:

> An Agent is responsible for managing connection persistence and reuse for HTTP clients.

From this I understand that an Agent is 'in charge' of managing a connection - and clearly, the fact that `https.Agent` exists on top of the 'plain' `http.Agent` exists would imply that it is 'in charge' of managing an HTTPS connection - hence the TLS configuration options it may receive.

My question is this - does this mean that the `Agent` in this case has an added responsibility of configuring the network security of the requests? this is a strange API if this is true - I would have expected to see the network connection config on a separate key for the `https.request` (as is shown in the example after the snippet above). Why overload the same object for another responsibility? Really, why have an `https.Agent` at all? The `http.Agent` should control connection pooling and keeping connections alive, while another layer should control configuring the actual requests. The `https.Agent` object doesn't seem well-defined to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually the [HTTPS doc](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_class_https_agent) points to some good resources, it also contains a link to [HTTPS module source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.12.0/lib/https.js), which reveals a lot. But to answer your questions:

> does this mean that the Agent in this case has an added responsibility of configuring the network security of the requests

Yes sort of, your HTTPS agent can perform custom security feature, or even use external HTTPS implementations, but for the built-in https.Agent, the native TLS module is used, and the options you passed to constructor is [ultimately passed to `tls.connect`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.12.0/lib/https.js#L129), allowing you to configure custom TLS options.

> Why overload the same object for another responsibility? Really, why have an https.Agent at all?

Because HTTPS runs on TLS. Actually `https.Agent` internally calls and constructs with `http.Agent`. The extra bits are mainly the use of SSL "session" over TCP "socket", if you search [getName in https.Agent](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.12.0/lib/https.js#L168) source and compare that to [http.Agent's](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.12.0/lib/_http_agent.js#L203), you will find the SSL session cache are based on many more fields, like DHparams, client cert, etc. things that does not exist for HTTP at all.